# Modify array of arrays to create custom array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays and I want to create an array of objects from it. There are custom properties to which I want to associate the sub-array values. I have the following array:

```
var testArray = [[1,5,10], [10,20,7], [11,10,25]];
```

I am modifying it to create the following

```
[{
    coordinates: [1, 5],
    reach: 10,
    power: 0
},
{
    coordinates: [10, 20],
    reach: 7,
    power: 0
},
{
    coordinates: [11, 10],
    reach: 25,
    power: 0
}]
```

For this I have written the following code.

```
function modifyArray(array) {
    return array.map(array => {
        return Object.assign({}, { coordinates: array.slice(0, 2), reach: array[2], power: 0 });
    });
}
```

I get the desired result. My question is if this is a good way to modify this type of data performance wise, since the function has two return statements. How can I improve on this code?

Comment: But can the original array be modified or not ? Do you have to preserve the original ?

Comment: I would like to preserve the original. However other way around could also be possible but not recommended.

Comment: But is your sole purpose to improve on speed ?

Comment: It was part of my coding challenge and I want to improve my solution to be acceptable as an "efficient" solution.

Comment: To make it efficient without mutating the original array you can remove both `assign` and `slice`. [Here is a jsperf i made on that](https://jsperf.com/so-codereview-modify-array/1)

Comment: Thank you it really helped. Is my solution acceptable in real cases after the changes proposed by @FreezePhoenix, without taking into consideration the actual time taken for each solution. Is it an efficient piece of code?

Comment: Yes i think its quite acceptable without the `Object.assign`. Now again it depends on the objective, hence my first question. If its not a code challenge that needs to meet  a specific run time then its more than fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

- You're overwriting the name `array` in defining the mapping param.
- You don't need to assign to a new object. This is done for you.

## Rewrite

```
function modifyArray(arrays) {
    return arrays.map(array => {
        return { coordinates: array.slice(0, 2), reach: array[2], power: 0 };
    });
}
```

Comment: is it ok to have a function with two return statements such as this, in terms of an efficient piece of code?

Comment: @Saqib two returns has no impact on performance, at all.